# problemas al traer datos de la base de datos y mostrarlos en cajas de texto para editarlos con Angularjs

Tags: php, html, angularjs

lo que pasa es que al momento de insertar los datos en el formulario algunos de los input lo tenemos que poner como type number para que pueda guardar en la base de datos y si los guarda, el probela es cuando queremos mandarlos a llamar y editarlos los datos que estan como type number no los muestra solo muestra los que estan en type text. y los que guardamos con los input type number en la base de datos tenemos la estructura que ese campo en la base de datos es tipo entero y double entonces como puedo hacer para que me los muestre y poderlos editar

formulario.html

```
<div ng-app="sa_app" ng-controller="controller" ng-init="show_data()">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" name="idproducto" id="idproducto" ng-model="idproducto" class="form-control" placeholder="ID Producto">  
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="producto" id="producto" ng-model= "producto" class="form-control" placeholder="Producto">  
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" ng-model="descripcion" class="form-control" placeholder="Descripcion">   
            <br/>
            <input type="number" name="existencia" id="existencia" ng-model="existencia" class="form-control" placeholder="Existencia"> 
            <br/>
            <input type="number" name="preciocompra" id="preciocompra" ng-model="preciocompra" class="form-control" placeholder="Precio de compra"> 
            <br/>
            <input type="number" name="precioventa" id="precioventa" ng-model="precioventa" class="form-control" placeholder="Precio de venta">
            <br/>
            <input type="number" name="idproveedor" id="idproveedor" ng-model="idproveedor" class="form-control" placeholder="ID Proveedor">    
            <br/>

            <input type="hidden" ng-model="idp">
            <input type="submit" name="insert" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="insert()" value="{{btnName}}">
        </div>
         </div>
```

inser.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bdga");
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
if (count($info) > 0) {

    $idproducto     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info->idproducto);
    $producto     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info->producto);
    $descripcion     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info->descripcion);
    $existencia    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info->existencia);
    $preciocompra     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info->preciocompra);
    $precioventa     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info->precioventa);
    $idproveedor    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $info->idproveedor);
    $btn_name = $info->btnName;
    if ($btn_name == "Insert") {
        $query = "INSERT INTO productos(idproducto,producto,descripcion,existencia,preciocompra,precioventa,idproveedor) VALUES ('$idproducto','$producto','$descripcion','$existencia','$preciocompra', '$precioventa', '$idproveedor')";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
            echo "Agregado con exito...";
        } else {
            echo 'Fallo';
        }
    }
    if ($btn_name == 'Edit') {
        $idp   = $info->idp;
        $query = "UPDATE productos SET idproducto = '$idproducto',producto = '$producto',descripcion = '$descripcion',existencia = '$existencia',preciocompra = '$preciocompra',precioventa = '$precioventa', idproveedor = '$idproveedor' WHERE idp = '$idp'";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
            echo 'Data Updated Successfully...';
        } else {
            echo 'Failed';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

script

```
<script>  
var app = angular.module("sa_app", []);
app.controller("controller", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.btnName = "Insert";
    $scope.insert = function() {
        if ($scope.idproducto == null) {
            alert("Ingresa el id del producto");
        } else if ($scope.producto == null) {
            alert("Ingresa Producto");
        } else if ($scope.descripcion == null) {
            alert("Ingresa descripcion");
        } else if ($scope.existencia == null) {
            alert("Ingresa existencia");
        } else if ($scope.preciocompra == null) {
            alert("Ingresa precio de compra");
        } else if ($scope.precioventa == null) {
            alert("Ingresa precio de venta");
        } else if ($scope.idproveedor == null) {
            alert("Ingresa id proveedor");          
        } else {
            $http.post(
                "insert.php", {
                    'idproducto': $scope.idproducto,
                    'producto': $scope.producto,
                    'descripcion': $scope.descripcion,
                    'existencia': $scope.existencia,
                    'preciocompra': $scope.preciocompra,
                    'precioventa': $scope.precioventa,
                    'idproveedor': $scope.idproveedor,
                    'btnName': $scope.btnName,
                    'idp': $scope.idp
                }
            ).success(function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $scope.idproducto = null;
                $scope.producto = null;
                $scope.descripcion = null;
                $scope.existencia = null;
                $scope.preciocompra = null;
                $scope.precioventa = null;
                $scope.idproveedor = null;
                $scope.btnName = "Insert";
                $scope.show_data();
            });
        }
    }
    $scope.show_data = function() {
        $http.get("display.php")
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.names = data;
            });
    }
    $scope.update_data = function(idp,idproducto,producto,descripcion,existencia,preciocompra,precioventa,idproveedor) {
        $scope.idp = idp;
        $scope.idproducto = idproducto;
        $scope.producto = producto;
        $scope.descripcion = descripcion;
        $scope.existencia = existencia;
        $scope.preciocompra = preciocompra;
        $scope.precioventa = precioventa;
        $scope.idproveedor = idproveedor;
        $scope.btnName = "Update";
    }
    $scope.delete_data = function(idp) {
        if (confirm("Seguro que deseas eliminar producto?")) {
            $http.post("delete.php", {
                    'idp': idp
                })
                .success(function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $scope.show_data();
                });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

display.php

```
<?php
$conn   = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bdga");
$output = array();
$query  = "SELECT * FROM productos";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El modelo de tu `input[type=number]` debe de ser de tipo `Number` para poder asignarlo. Si asignas un tipo de dato que no sea `Number`, angular no lo asignara al input porque le estas indicando un tipo de dato incompatible con el tipo del input.

Por ejemplo:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.numero = 00;
  $scope.asignarTexto = function() {
      $scope.numero = "111";
  }
   $scope.asignarNumeroParse = function() {
      $scope.numero = parseInt("111");
  }
  $scope.asignarNumero = function(){
    $scope.numero = 3333;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<input type="number" ng-model="numero" />
<div>
  <button ng-click="asignarTexto()">Asignar texto</button>  
  <button ng-click="asignarNumeroParse()"> Asignar numero utilizando parse</button>
  <button ng-click="asignarNumero()">Asignar numero</button>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Fijate como al dar clic sobre el buton *Asignar texto* no funciona pero con los demas si, esto porque los 2 restantes si asignan un tipo de dato Number mientras que el primero no.

Asi que tienes que asegurarte que le estas enviando un valor de tipo Number los `input[type=number]` ya sea utilizando `parseInt` o enviando directamente desde el servidor como tipo `Number`.